# How does FDM (Free Download Manager) determine a file's date and time?

Tags: file, http, pdf, download, download-manager

I assume many of you use download managers. I use the [Free Download Manager](https://www.freedownloadmanager.org/download.htm), and I like it a lot. But I am confused about how this valuable tool determines the date and time of the file it downloads.

For example, I downloaded the PDF file from
https://www.cusd80.com/cms/lib/AZ01001175/Centricity/Domain/10180/The%20Crucible%20Anchor%20Text.pdf

And it sets the file's date-time as following
| Created: ‎Friday, ‎September ‎20, ‎2019, ‏‎6:12:36 PM

When I checked HTTP headers, I found this information
| last-modified: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 15:22:28 GMT

When I checked the creation date-time recorded in the PDF file, I found
| Created: Wed, 12 Sep 2018 8:21:12 GMT

---

Does anyone have any idea where the 2019 date listed above comes from?

Comment: @KJ – The link works fine. Also, the downloader should not use alternative source for this file, I believe.

Comment: @KJ – It works even with Incognito mode (no cookies). I assume you're experiencing some geo-blocking

Comment: @Ωmega It doesn't work for me either - *"Request blocked. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
"*

Comment: Seems like FDM uses the file's original modified date which is bloody annoying. Wishing there was a setting for that in FDM preferences, but there isnt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uncheck the option "use server time for file creation" under
preferences -> general -> downloads. this will the creation time actual download time

Comment: Yeah! That's it. You rock. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

When you download a file It has a date the file was stored on the server in this case we see the server file modified date

```
curl -i https://www.cusd80.com/cms/lib/AZ01001175/Centricity/Domain/10180/The%20Crucible%20Anchor%20Text.pdf
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Length: 6020870
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Mon, 17 Apr 2023 20:41:22 GMT
Cache-Control: private
```

**Last-Modified: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 22:12:36 GMT**

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "921b4682070d51:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains;
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self' https://*.ally.ac;
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 64f1d594216061fb1311499e08a4ee1a.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Pop: LHR61-P4
X-Amz-Cf-Id: 0e3WxAEhhry-z_piciSaut39s-PqkiC2llRWUKETJ8P_P-Jsu5FRvA==
```

The time is relative to time zone so on download the local times may be hours different. Note the difference with my curl time (22:12) and OP observation of 6:12 PM (18:12)

My copy says **current time for both created and mod** because I simply download without a File Manager with

```
curl -O https://www.cusd80.com/cms/lib/AZ01001175/Centricity/Domain/10180/The%20Crucible%20Anchor%20Text.pdf
```

Internally the file has multiple dates but the two most commonly shown will be via file details but neither nor both have to be shown.

[image]

```
3 0 obj
<</CreationDate(D:20180912082112)/Creator(PDFium)/Producer(PDFium)>>
endobj
```

NOTE: the time inside or outside a PDF does not need to be true it can be past or future but must be not less than any 4 digits for a nominal year. However for certain tests all dates should concur for all of one or all of the other except when using update tracking, but can still be spoofed, to say modified before creation!